# Mendeley and Citavi ignore previous references and act to them as normal text and start again from one

Tags: ms-word, reference, mendeley

both Citavi and Mendeley referencing management, when I referenced in MS [image]Word, it works fine, but after two or three days ( after several restarting my computer), it ignores previous citation and restart again from one. I want to keep continue to 3 in example.

[![I used three different references, two of them is fine, but the third one, it starts again from one, but it should be three.]]

Comment: This is not a programming question. Questions on general Word usage are off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on an appropriate end-user forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: I searched about it before, there are many questions about Mendeley in StackOverflow, that is way I posted, if you think it is not suitable, I am going to remove, do you think??

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Mendeley MS plugin. I think it is fine.